# Would it be possible to create a virtual camera, then feed video input to it with node-webcam?

Tags: node.js, webcam

Would it be possible to create a virtual camera, then feed video input to it with node-webcam? If not is there a way i could do this without writing my own driver (doesnt have to be nodejs)?